# where to find structure tab in umbraco 7.4?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6

I am currently working on Umbraco CMS and want to manage hierarchy like master -> home -> TestPage
but i can't find structure tab anymore, can anyone know where to find it in newer version ?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be looking in the upper right corner. :) I think what you're looking for is "Compositions" or the "Permissions" to allow certain doctypes under other doctypes.

[image]

Update:

From the comments it seems like you want to make nested content types. This is still possible in the exact way it was possible before, right-click on the document type that you want to use as a parent and choose "Create".

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you make a screenshot or video?

Comment: hey @sebastiaan i want to create new menu like inside master -> there is a home and inside home there is one more menu called test, i mean to say child node inside home tab..if i click on allow access on root then it will be displayed in root not in child node...are you getting it ?